# ASP.NET MVC Using Authentication with external JWT

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, jwt

I have created a Web API with a login method that authenticates against AzureAD returns a JWT string.

Now I have a presentation MVC app where I want to use this login method against. I'm trying to figure out how to use the built in Authentication in ASP.NET to authenticate users using this jwt string. All examples I find is using Identity for example, or external login methods like Facebook/Twitter.

I know I can use the jwt as a cookie in the frontend, but preferably I'd like to use it with the built-in functionality in ASP.NET to use [Authentication]-tags across my MVC-controllers.

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api?force_isolation=true#sending-an-unauthorized-request

Answer (score 0):

I searched a lot, no one in the world knows, I think everyone is using vue or angular. I don't think anyone is using mvc.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).